# Unicode characters not rendered when running jar file in terminal ( Eclipse / MacOS )

Tags: java, eclipse, unicode, jar, ascii

I have a Java project in Eclipse with ascii characters in it (◊ , ‡ , etc). When I export the project as an executable jar, and run that jar in the terminal (java -jar fileName.jar), the ascii characters are rendered as a '?'. It displays fine in the Eclipse console, but they aren't recognized in the terminal.

I originally had it as just the character ( ◊ , · , — ) in the code, then changed it to unicode in hope of that fixing it (\u25CA \u00B7 \u2014) with no luck. It was the same scenario, displayed in Eclipse, but not in the terminal. Is there a way to export it to allow these characters to be displayed?

I hope this was decently clear. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Check in Terminal Preferences under encodings and see if it is defaulted to something that doesn't support your characters, and/or try changing the font used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to set -Dfile.encoding=utf-8, and also make sure that your terminal is UTF-8.

Comment: What command takes this argument? Javac? Jar? Please elaborate. Thanks!